# JsonMessage cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, log4j2, eclipse-classpath

I'm trying this log4j2 sample for flowtracing.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/flowtracing.html

My eclipse is complaining that JsonMessage cannot be resolved to a type.

In my pom.xml I have the dependencies

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When I browse the log4j-api-2.11.0.jar in Eclipse/Maven Dependencies section of the project I cannot find JsonMessage.class in the org.apache.logging.log4j.message package.

I went online to see if JsonMessage is in the github source control https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-api/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/JsonMessage.java and it is there.

What can I do to bring JsonMessage into my project and get the sample to build and run?

Comment: I don't see `JsonMessage` in the [list of message classes provided by log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/messages.html) and the link to the source in your question points to the test source not main - src/**test**/java...

Comment: The fastest thing to do is probably just download the source for the JsonMessage class and add it to your project's main src

Comment: That is what I did and compiled the project.  Is JsonMessage used just for testing or should it be included in the master branch?

Comment: Well, since it seems to only be used in src/test/java I'd say it's just used for testing.